# Material design input text field label is in incorrect place after focus

Tags: material-design, vuetify.js

I have code like this:

```
<v-text-field label="Outlined" outlined />
```

After I focus this input text is going top left corner of input as expected but it's actually hovering the line:

[image]

What might be the reason?

---

I was trying to debug it and I find this very weird to me. Basically the label element has binded style left: 0 and position absolute ofcourse, then the outer dic which is .v-text-field-slot has position relative but the label is not actually starting at 0px from the left

[image]

It doesn't have any padding or something either:

[image]

So basically I have no clue why it doesn't stick to left side of the outer relative positioned div.

Actually thanks to Firefox I found out where the issue lays:

[image]

Because of the transform scale to 0.75 it's not at the very left of outer div. I'm now trying to find out the fix and I'm wondering why Vuetify didn't handle that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I acutally found solution by modifing `.v-label--active` class:

```
.v-label--active {
    transform: translateY(-28px) scale(1) !important;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    padding-right: 8px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

but it's more like hack than real solution. Also if I will have this on some other background then white, it will look bad. So basically I'm still looking for solution but for now I'll move on with above css.

---

Edit: The real solution was that I was missing `<v-app></v-app>` wraping my entire app.